# jQuery clone not working in IE8 -- looking to convert to cloneNode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div of checkboxes that I need cloned (just the checked boxes) and appended to a form before the form gets submitted. This has been working fine in all browsers I've tested with aside from IE8.

Code:

```
$("#hidden_states").append($('#states_container :input').clone());
$("form#form_submission").submit();
```

With IE8, none of the checkboxes get properly cloned. I'm pretty sure this is because of jQuery's clone() function.

I'm looking for a way to make this so it works with IE8. I've tried cloneNode() :

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('#states_container :input')
var hs = document.getElementById('hidden_states');

var clone = div.cloneNode(true);

$("#hidden_states").append(clone);
```

...and a number of other things which didn't work. I just realized, too, querySelectorAll isn't going to work in IE8. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure this is because of jQuery's clone() function." That seems unlikely, and a bug if so...

Comment: Which jquery version are you using, ensure you are using jquery 1.x and not 2.x
Version 2.x drops support for older browsers, ie6,7,8 are not supported.

Comment: Go to IE8 Console(F12), and paste here the error for help us to help you.

Comment: Joao: no error is coming up in the console in IE8 mode, oddly.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: Oddly enough, when I make the appended div visible, it shows up. Everything seems to work in IE8 aside from submission...